# How does Matlab produce thin edges?

Tags: matlab, sobel

Im using sobel edge detection.

[Here is the sample image file if you have Matlab](https://www.mediafire.com/?poicg39pyxj1834)
[image]

How does Matlab, by itself manage to achieve very thin edges like this one (using just the Matlab's edge function with 'sobel' as parameter)

```
matlabsobel = edge(originalImage,'sobel')
imshow(matlabsobel)
```

[image]

but when I try to do sobel algorithm my own way, assuming the process is just the same..

```
originalImage = gaussianizedimage;
threshold = 60.5;
k = [1 2 1; 0 0 0; -1 -2 -1];
H = conv2(double(originalImage),k, 'same');
V = conv2(double(originalImage),k','same');
E = sqrt(H.*H + V.*V);
edgeImage = uint8((E > threshold) * 255);
imshow(edgeImage);
title('sobel algorithm')
```

[image]

Why is that its different? What is still lacking in my implementation to achieve Matlab's thin edges?

Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you get with Matlab's algorithm when you use the "nothinning" option?

Comment: @Benoit_11 by default, if we execute matlabsobel = edge(originalImage,'sobel'),, it always show thin edges... There is nothinning option with the edge function

Comment: They probably use non-maximum suppression as well as a variety of other things.  `sobel` is probably the first step in estimating the local gradient.  If you actually do `edit edge` in the command prompt, you may be able to see what they're doing under the hood.  I don't have MATLAB here, so I can't verify that for you.

Comment: yes that was my point; if you tell Matlab not to thin edges I was wondering if the image would look like yours

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to rayryeng

Sobel is the first step, and in order to get thin edges, you need to perform skelotinization

```
>> BW3 = bwmorph(bww,'skel',Inf);
>> figure()
>> imshow(BW3)
```

The resulting image is the following

[image]